# UITableView Scroll to top with SearchController in tableView header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

So I have a tableView. It's header is an UISearchController which hides the navigation controller. I want when the user searches or taps on Cancel on the search controller, to scroll that tableView to the top.

The problem is that

```
let top = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(top, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: false)
```

actually scrolls to the top of the tableView, which in this case, is the Y of the SearchController, so half my cell, is behind the search controller at this point.

```
tableView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectZero, animated: false)
```

has the same behavior.

Example after search:

[image]

Comment: have you disabled automatically adjust scroll view insets??

Comment: @VishalSonawane yep, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to get it to work by redoing everything and scrolling with:

```
func scrollToTableViewTop() {
    tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem and I think this happens because of scope titles, try this one :)

```
self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [NSArray array]
```

Or you can set the top header height

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44.0
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting contentoffset of tableview

```
tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, searchBar.bounds.size.height);
```